# PGP file decryption\

Tags: go, encryption, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, pgp

I am looking for suggestions on how to use openPGP to decrypt a PGP encrypted file we receive externally. The file is placed on a Google Cloud bucket and I am planning to use a Cloud function to run the decryption.

There are several examples ([this](https://github.com/jchavannes/go-pgp/blob/master/pgp/encrypt_test.go) and [this](https://github.com/jchavannes/go-pgp)) on the web with Go and OpenPGP but they are limited to decrypting strings/texts and not files. The file is encrypted using a traditional PGP encrypt command.

I am trying to avoid creating a VM or asking the external agency to change the encryption process.

Comment: "they are limited to decrypting strings/texts and not files". I don't follow. strings (or, more precisely, byte slices) are more general than files. What's stopping you from reading the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your [example linked](https://github.com/jchavannes/go-pgp/blob/master/pgp/encrypt_test.go) you can see that it [decrypts](https://github.com/jchavannes/go-pgp/blob/master/pgp/encrypt_test.go#L30) a byte slice `[]byte`. It can be the content from an encrypted file.

You can replace the

```
    decrypted, err := pgp.Decrypt(privEntity, encrypted)
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
    }
```

by

```
    encrypted, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
    }

    decrypted, err := pgp.Decrypt(privEntity, encrypted)
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
    }
```

Comment: So, is it possible to encrypt whole file using same logic? Does [ ]byte has and limitations?

Comment: Except for you max ram, no. You can load a big file in your ram, and encrypt its content that you would store in a `[]byte`. You can see how to do that in the same example: https://github.com/jchavannes/go-pgp/blob/master/pgp/encrypt_test.go#L11-L21

Comment: But for a big file, I would preferably use a `io.Reader` to read the original file before sending to the Encrypt io.WriterCloser.


https://gist.github.com/dolanor/575345285cafa3164db6ab842332b892